# Is there a way to move a question to one of the Trilogy sites?

Tags: support

Opps, both questions ([1095](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/1095/how-to-ignore-certain-coding-standard-errors-in-php-codesniffer), [1247](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/1247/can-i-skip-the-pem-pass-phrase-question-when-i-restart-nginx)) I've asked on Pro Webmasters have had feedback saying they would be best asked on one of the Trilogy (StackOverflow, ServerFault and SuperUser) sites. Is there a way to move them or should I delete them and re-create on the relevant site?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://meta.webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/5/vote-to-close-belongs-on

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the moment you'll need to recreate them on the relevant site. In the short term it might be an idea to leave the questions here but closed as being "off topic" with a comment pointing to the new question.

This means that if someone else comes here with a similar question they'll see yours (hopefully) and not post.

If this site takes off there will be migration options to "related" sites. See [this answer on meta.stackoverflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52141/will-it-be-possible-to-migrate-questions-between-the-trilogy-and-the-stack-exchan/54524#54524) from Jeff himself.

> ... this will be possible.
>
> The trick here is that we'll only "unlock" question migration paths between sites that have an some kind of rational relationship, so the odds of that off-topic (but on-topic for the other network site) question being asked has some actual chance of occuring in the real world.

Once the site is established then delete the questions.

**UPDATE**

Since this answer was posted an option to migrate questions to *any* site in the Stack Exchange network has been added to the moderator's close dialog. So the correct answer is to now flag the post for moderator attention and ask for it to be migrated. If a moderator agrees then they will migrate it for you.

Comment: moderators can migrate questions between any arbitrary site, so flag for mod attention if the question is not on a standard path